# ASP.NET MVC 5: How do I add a dropdown list using an IEnumumerble from a ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have three tables being combined on this form. The drop down list is to show all possible brand names in our database and return the UID for that brand. I've tried many different ways to solve this but to no avail. Currently I am getting an error saying, 'Cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a delegate type.' So I must be using the DropDownList helper wrong.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class AlternateCodeViewModel
{
    //public web2_item_alternate_code web2_item_alternate_code { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int inv_mast_uid { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Alternate Code")]
    public string Alternate_Code_Item_ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Alternate_Code_Brand_ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1)]
    [Display(Name = "Exact Flag")]
    public string Exact_Flag { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1)]
    [Display(Name = "Delete Flag")]
    public string Delete_Flag { get; set; }

    public int item_brand_uid { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<web2_item_brands> web2_item_brands { get; set; }
    public inv_mast inv_mast { get; set; }


}`
```

Here is my controller:

Here is my View:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.web2_item_brands, "Brand Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.web2_item_brands, Model.web2_item_brands, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.web2_item_brands, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects (which is what `IEnumerable<web2_item_brands> web2_item_brands` is). You need to bind it to a property which is a value type (e.g. `int` or `string`) but its not clear from your model what that should be (perhaps `int item_brand_uid`?).

Comment: Next, the second parameter of `DropDownListFor()` must be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, so `Model.web2_item_brands` wont work because that is `IEnumerable<web2_item_brands>`. You need to generate a `SelectList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind dropdownlist to selectlistitems and not other complex types.  Something like this.

**Models**

```
public class AlternateCodeViewModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int inv_mast_uid { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Alternate Code")]
    public string Alternate_Code_Item_ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Alternate_Code_Brand_ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1)]
    [Display(Name = "Exact Flag")]
    public string Exact_Flag { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1)]
    [Display(Name = "Delete Flag")]
    public string Delete_Flag { get; set; }

    public int item_brand_uid { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<web2_item_brands> web2_item_brands { get; set; }
    public inv_mast inv_mast { get; set; }

}

public class inv_mast
{

}

public class web2_item_brands
{
    public int item_brand_uid { get; set; }
    public string item_brand_text { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller action**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new AlternateCodeViewModel
        {
            web2_item_brands = 
                new[] 
                {new web2_item_brands 
                    { item_brand_text = "text", item_brand_uid = 1}
                }
        });
    }
}
```

**Markup code**

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@model Test.ViewModels.AlternateCodeViewModel

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.item_brand_uid, 
        Model.web2_item_brands.Select(s => 
            new SelectListItem { Value = s.item_brand_uid.ToString(), Text = s.item_brand_text}), 
        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

note: I have no idea what this complex type web2_item_brands represents, therefore I declared a simple class with the same name above just to show you the usage.